# Problem using Position when using a variable

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

So,

I tried to use Position to get the Position of the 90% Maximum of a Photodiode Signal. The code works when i directly use the solution of the .9*Max[...] solution, but I want to have it with a Variable in Position. The problem is as long as i dont use the numerical value but some variable I get a empty solution {}

My code right now is:

```
Position[datapd[6][[All, 2]], nearest[datapd[6]]]

(* {} *)
```

which is not working while:

```
Position[datapd[6][[All, 2]], 0.566794]
(* {{735}} *)
```

is giving me the right result...

while datapd is my `{time,voltage}` list and `nearest[datapd[6]]` is my code giving me the 90% of my Voltage maximum. The code for `nearest[...]` is:

```
nearest[x_[nr_]] := Nearest[x[nr][[All, 2]], .9*Max[x[nr][[All, 2]]]]
```

which gives me for my datapd[6] list:

```
nearest[datapd[6]]


(* {0.566794} *)
```

I read something about Mathematica having Problems if the numbers of the Position input is somewhat different from the list element your looking for after some digits. But in my case the numerical value should be exactly the same.

I also tried using `//N` and also giving `Position` some condition with `n_/;n==nearest[...]` but it wont do the thing but just run and run.

Does somebody has any advices to fix this problem?

Comment: What about a short example data set?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I'm glad this solved your problem. Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake and is unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp) and don't forget the [tour] so you get a nice *Informed* badge.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
nearest[datapd[6]]
(* {0.566794} *)
```

Implies that `Position[datapd[6][[All, 2]], nearest[datapd[6]]]` searches for `{0.566794}` instead of `0.566794`

Try

```
Position[datapd[6][[All, 2]], First@nearest[datapd[6]]]
```

Comment: Thanks!! That did the job.